# iPhone UIImage initWithData fails

Tags: iphone, uikit

I'm trying to code up an async image downloader. I use NSURLConnection to get the data into an NSMutableData and use that data once it is complete to initialize a UIImage.

I checked the bytes and it downloads the entire image correctly (right number of bytes at least), however; when I call

```
[UIImage imageWithData:data]
```

and then check the properties of the image, it is zero width and a garbage number for height, in fact, same number no matter what the image is. I tried with bunch of different images, png, jpg, different urls, it always downloads the image completely but UIImage can't initialize with that data. What could I be doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Code is really as you'd expect it to look like:

Connection Delegate:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {
[[ImageManager sharedInstance] dataDownloadedBy:self]; }
```

ImageManager:

```
-(void)dataDownloadedBy:(WebConnection *)connection{    
WebImage *image = [[WebImage alloc] initWithLink:connection.url];
[image setImageFromData:connection.data];
[images addObject:image];
[connection release];}
```

WebImage:

```
-(void)setImageFromData:(NSMutableData *)data{
image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];}
```

Comment: You probably need to post the code where you download the data and initialize the data object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm sure the UIImage will not initialize with garbage data. The constructor  `initWithData` analyzes the data to determine the file format. If your data is corrupted, the image returned will be nil. Check this at first.

```
-(void)dataDownloadedBy:(WebConnection *)connection{    
    WebImage *image = [[WebImage alloc] initWithLink:connection.url];
    [image setImageFromData:connection.data];
    if (image.image != nil) { [images addObject:image]; }
    [connection release];
}
```

Second, make sure you append the data during the download process. Here is the callback method:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

Finally, your code must absolutely includes the second case: a download failure.

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [connection release];
}
```

Your problem description lacks some important pieces of code.

The URLCache demo from Apple is a very good project to understand async image download.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/URLCache/Introduction/Intro.html

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what is wrong, it could be you don't use the release properly, say i don't know why you release connection at the end of dataDownloadedBy, it is supposed to be image ?
it could help if you post more your code here.

I used to do the same thing, you can have a look the post here
http://blog.163.com/lionyue@126/blog/static/1079307120096895433277/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If initWithData is failing, most likely the image data you're getting is corrupt.  You should save it to a file like this:

```
[data writeToFile:@"/tmp/foo.jpg" atomically:NO];
```

and then try to open it in Preview.app.

Answer (score 0):

a different problem, but that gives teh same painful error is if You ask for a file that is not reachable: HTTP server will give back error 404 message, your code read that bytes (they are NOT valid bytes for an image, AND You will got NIL.